# How to manage test cases using Confluence?

Tags: testing, confluence

We would like to use Confluence for writing and managing our test cases. Confluence Testplan plugin seems close to what I'm looking for, but it's a bit too simple and limited.

How are you using Confluence to manage your test cases?

Answer (score 7):

We both do and don't use Confluence for managing our test cases.

**We Don't** 
In my project we use, and love, Confluence. But only for knowledge documentation and spreading. I'm sorry but I can't see how Confluence would be a good idea of writing and managing our test cases.

**We Do** 
We use excel/calc spreadsheets to write an manage manual test cases. We write them on a very high level. E.g. "Log in and upload a jpeg image." We expect all tester to have high domain knowledge and know how to log in and upload images.
Then we upload the spreadsheets to Confluence a special page. Every time the tests are run, before every release/sprint demo, we check those out. We enter in the results (sometimes add new tests) and check the spreadsheet back in again with comments.
It works fine, is fast, flexible, low overhead and it's ready to send to management or the customer anytime.

IMHO, honestly spreadsheets beats most test managing tools.

Comment: Please use two newlines to create a line break, rather than `<br>`. It's a heck of a lot easier to read.

Comment: but do we have any way to modify spreadsheet directly on confluence page. it should help for parallel modification.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you are using Jira for Agile management, it is best practice to associate test cases with Jira tickets. Confluence does a nice job of allowing users to link user stories within the wiki. For instance you can create a 'sub task' against a user story. Typically I write automated tests for all the user stories I test. So I can associate a git commit with a particular QA sub-task so it makes sense linking a ticket. You might want to look at the Confluence api, I link my automated test results into confluence which prints out my test cases.

On the topic of using spreasheets.. Its a terrible practice. Test Cases should be accessible by anyone and I don't mean on shared drive somewhere. Product, management and anyone in engineering should be able to visit a page and look at the test cases, coverage & results.

Answer (score 1):

If the question is about functional testing or BDD, did you check [GreenPepper](http://www.greenpeppersoftware.com/confluence/display/GPW/Home/)? See the [documentation](http://www.greenpeppersoftware.com/confluence/display/GPO/Documentation).

Answer (score -1):

We're not using Confluence for test cases right now, but we are for use cases. I wrote up some examples about how we manage use cases [here](http://nvisia.com/techs/?p=367). The general idea could probably be applied to test cases also.

Comment: Yeah, looks like my previous employer took it down. I'll have to look for another copy.